# Sum Of Total Values in a columns after filtering using jquery in html table

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Hi I want To add only (Received Amount,Paid Amount and Balance Amount) column and output the total calculation in a Total field after filtering in a searchbox. Now the calculations only happen when we enter in this page but when we want to filter data in searchbox the sum of values cannot be changed. I attach a picture in which we have 2 bank accounts sbi and hdfc. when we search HDFC then only calculations performed for this particular type.

Image of what it looks like now

[image]

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('table thead th').each(function(i) {
    calculateColumn(i);
  });
});

function calculateColumn(index) {
  var total = 0;
  $('table tr').each(function() {
    var value = parseInt($('td', this).eq(index).text());
    if (!isNaN(value)) {
      total += value;
    }
  });
  $('table tfoot td').eq(index).text('Total: ' + total);
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  var table = $('#example').DataTable({
    lengthChange: false,
    buttons: ['copy', 'excel', 'pdf', 'colvis']
  });

  table.buttons().container()
    .appendTo('#example_wrapper .col-md-6:eq(0)');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" />
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.6.2/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <br>
  <h3>Statement of Accounts</h3>
  <br>
  <div class="table-responsive">
    <table id="example" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-responsive-xl">
      <thead class="thead-dark">
        <tr>
          <th>Voucher Date</th>
          <th>Voucher No</th>
          <th>Party Name</th>
          <th>Instrument No</th>
          <th>From Bank</th>
          <th>To Bank</th>
          <th class="a">Recieved Amount</th>
          <th class="a">Paid Amount</th>
          <th class="a">Balance Amount</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>26/05/2020</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>XYZ</td>
          <td>123</td>
          <td>HDFC</td>
          <td>SBI</td>
          <td>50000</td>
          <td>20000</td>
          <td>30000</td>
        </tr>

      </tbody>
      <tfoot>
        <tr class="totalColumn">
          <td style="visibility:hidden;"></td>
          <td style="visibility:hidden;"> </td>
          <td style="visibility:hidden;"> </td>
          <td style="visibility:hidden;"> </td>
          <td style="visibility:hidden;"> </td>
          <td style="visibility:hidden;"> </td>
          <td>Total:</td>
          <td>Total:</td>
          <td>Total:</td>
        </tr>
      </tfoot>
    </table>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Please click edit, then `[<>]` snippet editor and post PURE HTML/CSS and Script ONLY. It is a JS problem, not a Python problem. We need a [mcve]

Comment: Hey can u give me the answer of this question

Comment: Possibly if you first do what I asked

Comment: PURE HTML, JS and CSS!!!! I do not have a server nor time to install your code on it

Comment: @mplungjan There is only a loop which iterate items in a row thats it

Comment: But there is not relevant DATA. Please remove ALL TEMPLATING and make ONE SNIPPET with JS, HTML and CSS - have 3 lines of data or so

Comment: Your question was a mess. I have tried to improve it. I still get error in the snippet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do your calculations again redrawing of table after search completion

So you have to bind an event `draw.dt`

In your code you have to add these lines

```
$('#example').on('draw.dt', function() {
    $('table thead th').each(function(i) {
      calculateColumn(i);
    });
  });
```

Working example, try searching for HDFC

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('table thead th').each(function(i) {
    calculateColumn(i);
  });
});

function calculateColumn(index) {
  var total = 0;
  $('table tr').each(function() {
    var value = parseInt($('td', this).eq(index).text());
    if (!isNaN(value)) {
      total += value;
    }
  });
  $('table tfoot td').eq(index).text('Total: ' + total);
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  var table = $('#example').DataTable({
    lengthChange: false,
    buttons: ['copy', 'excel', 'pdf']
  });

  table.buttons().container()
    .appendTo('#example_wrapper .col-md-6:eq(0)');

  $('#example').on('draw.dt', function() {
    $('table thead th').each(function(i) {
      calculateColumn(i);
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" />
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.6.2/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <br>
  <h3>Statement of Accounts</h3>
  <br>
  <div class="table-responsive">
    <table id="example" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-responsive-xl">
      <thead class="thead-dark">
        <tr>
          <th>Voucher Date</th>
          <th>Voucher No</th>
          <th>Party Name</th>
          <th>Instrument No</th>
          <th>From Bank</th>
          <th>To Bank</th>
          <th class="a">Recieved Amount</th>
          <th class="a">Paid Amount</th>
          <th class="a">Balance Amount</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>26/05/2020</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>XYZ</td>
          <td>123</td>
          <td>HDFC</td>
          <td>SBI</td>
          <td>50000</td>
          <td>20000</td>
          <td>30000</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td>26/05/2020</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>XYZ</td>
          <td>123</td>
          <td>SBI</td>
          <td>SBI</td>
          <td>50000</td>
          <td>20000</td>
          <td>30000</td>
        </tr>

      </tbody>
      <tfoot>
        <tr class="totalColumn">
          <td style="visibility:hidden;"></td>
          <td style="visibility:hidden;"> </td>
          <td style="visibility:hidden;"> </td>
          <td style="visibility:hidden;"> </td>
          <td style="visibility:hidden;"> </td>
          <td style="visibility:hidden;"> </td>
          <td>Total:</td>
          <td>Total:</td>
          <td>Total:</td>
        </tr>
      </tfoot>
    </table>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: @PulkitArora Glad it helped. You can mark it as accepted answer. So that community gets to know this is helpful answer, so in future another user looking for same can get help from here. Also I will some reps points :P